# How to achieve glOrthof in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to convert my `OpenGL ES 1` application to a `OpenGL ES 2` application to be able to use Shaders. Now I use the glOrthof function to have a "real sized viewport" so I can place the vertices at the "actual" pixel in the OpenGL View.

```
glOrthof(0, _frame.size.width, _frame.size.height, 0, -1, 1);
```

I am having trouble finding out how to achieve this in `OpenGL ES 2`, is there anyone who can show me how to do this?

If not, does anyone have a link to a good `OpenGL ES 1 to OpenGL ES 2` tutorial/explanation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `glOrtho` method does nothing else than create a new matrix and multiply the current projection matrix by this matrix. With OpenGL ES 2.0 you have to manage matrices yourself. In order to replicate the `glOrtho` behaviour you need a uniform for the projection matrix in your vertex shader, which you then multiply your vertices with. Usually you also have a model and a view matrix (or a combined modelview matrix, like in OpenGL ES 1) which you transform your vertices with before the projection transform:

```
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

attribute vec4 vertex;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * (modelview * vertex);
}
```

The specific projection matrix that `glOrtho` constructs can be found [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glOrtho.xml).

Comment: Could you show me how to create/load the projection and modelview?

Comment: @MrThys If you're not sure about that, you should first really consult some learning resources on OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLSL shaders. Basically, once you have the corresponding uniform locations and the shader program is bound/used, you can set their values with one of the many [`glUniform...`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) calls, in the case of matrices you'd use `glUniformMatrix4fv`

Comment: @HaukeStrasdat What the... you're right! How can such a canonic reference be dead? Fine, now all we got left are stupid ES reference pages. But ok, at least for this answer they're a good fit.

Comment: updated link:  https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glOrtho.xml  but looks like the conversion of docs to HTML lost essential '/'s and '()'s. Comparing to Brad Larson's answer, the doc may be trying to say  `2/(right-left)  0  0  tx    0  2/(top-bottom)  0  ty    0  0  -2/(far-near)  tz    0  0  0  1`. Where `tx = -(right+left)/(right-left)`, `ty = -(top+bottom)/(top-bottom)`, `tz = -(far+near)/(far-near)`.  This differs from Larson's answer in one place: matrix[10] is `-2/(far-near)`, but Larson's does not have the minus sign `2 / f_n`.  So z is inverted. Try it both ways...

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The minus should be there, though. Z has to be inverted, since the eye-space has the camera looking towards -Z, but in NDC/window space we have +1 = far away.

Answer (score 10):

As Christian describes, all of the matrix math for processing your vertices is up to you, so you have to replicate the matrix that `glOrthof()` creates.  In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449095/how-do-i-set-up-the-viewable-area-in-a-scene-within-opengl-es-2-0/6474528#6474528), I provided the following Objective-C method for generating such an orthographic projection matrix:

```
- (void)loadOrthoMatrix:(GLfloat *)matrix left:(GLfloat)left right:(GLfloat)right bottom:(GLfloat)bottom top:(GLfloat)top near:(GLfloat)near far:(GLfloat)far;
{
    GLfloat r_l = right - left;
    GLfloat t_b = top - bottom;
    GLfloat f_n = far - near;
    GLfloat tx = - (right + left) / (right - left);
    GLfloat ty = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    GLfloat tz = - (far + near) / (far - near);

    matrix[0] = 2.0f / r_l;
    matrix[1] = 0.0f;
    matrix[2] = 0.0f;
    matrix[3] = tx;

    matrix[4] = 0.0f;
    matrix[5] = 2.0f / t_b;
    matrix[6] = 0.0f;
    matrix[7] = ty;

    matrix[8] = 0.0f;
    matrix[9] = 0.0f;
    matrix[10] = 2.0f / f_n;
    matrix[11] = tz;

    matrix[12] = 0.0f;
    matrix[13] = 0.0f;
    matrix[14] = 0.0f;
    matrix[15] = 1.0f;
}
```

The matrix used here is defined as

```
GLfloat orthographicMatrix[16];
```

I then apply the matrix within my vertex shader using something like the following:

```
gl_Position = modelViewProjMatrix * position * orthographicMatrix;
```

My multiplication order differs from Christian's, so I may be doing something a little backward here, but this is what I've used to handle this within an OpenGL ES 2.0 application of mine (the source code of which can be found [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules)).

Comment: Your method seems exactly to match the formula given by the glOrthof man page (e.g. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)

Comment: The orthographic matrix is actually the projection matrix, but the name `modelViewProjMatrix` suggests that you have another projection matrix, which is a bit strange conceptually (although valid, what's not possible with shaders). But what is really strange is that you mix left-application with right-application of matrix transformations to vectors. And that's the reason you actually create the transposed matrix in your `loadOrthoMatrix` routine (and the reason why this shader code should cause utter confusion to anybody not that deep into matrix transformations).

Comment: @Christian - You really can tell that matrix math isn't one of my strong areas.  The naming for the shader was left over from another implementation, and really should be just the model view matrix for the first component.  I figured that this was a case of two lefts making a right, but it had worked when I tried it so I never questioned why.  Thanks for pointing out the oddities here.

Comment: `matrix[10] = -2.0f / f_n;` // correct missing minus sign — see docs